# Which order should service packs be installed

Tags: windows-server-2003, service-pack

We have a test environment that is not connected to the internet so we cannot run windows update.

I need to install windows 2003 service pack 2.

We have a domain controller and two web servers.

What I was wondering is: Is there any particular order in which I should update the servers? Does it matter if I run the update on the domain controller or the web servers first? Could I run the update on all 3 machines at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't matter which machines get the service pack first.  Personally, I like to do domain controllers first because they're sort of the like the hub of the infrastructure.  The "newer" they are, the better things seem to work with them.